# Background Page in popup- chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am embedding a dynamic webpage in a popup. Currently its working and every time popup is loaded the webpage is loaded again, thus me losing the work i did on the webpage in popup. Though its fine, but i want that webpage remain loaded in background and i just show it in popup on click. to do this i copied complete code from my pop up page(script+html) to background.html. Now how should i access the page completely in popup and show directly(i want to show html also-from background page)

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Popups live in the same process (the extension process) as the background page, and one page can get the DOM Window of the other. A popup gets the background page by calling `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`. So every time you open the popup, just read and write to some variable on the background page, for example `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().enteredData = "value";`.

Alternately, you can use [HTML5 localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#methods) to store variables even after the browser is shut down; e.g. `localStorage['enteredData'] = "value"`.

Comment: This only works for saving javascript.  There's no way to maintain the DOM state of an actual html page between popup open/closes.